# Console Output and User Input in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I am working on a GUI and I want the user to be able to press the "Answer" button and then the console will print on `textarea2` with user input enabled as well. What would I have to do to get the JTextArea (`textarea2`) to function as a console and print the text in the `insertquestions` method along with accepting user input?

```
package Scrambler;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GUI extends JFrame {

    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    private JButton button1;
    private JButton button2;
    private JPanel panel1;
    private JPanel panel2;
    private JTextField textfield2;
    private JTextArea textarea;
    private JTextArea textarea2;
    private JTextField textfield5;
    private JTextField textfield7;

    public GUI() {

        this.setTitle("UnScrambleGUI");
        this.setSize(500, 400);
        generateMenu();
        this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(null);
        contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
        contentPane.setBackground(new Color(192, 192, 192));


        button1 = new JButton();
        button1.setBounds(56, 341, 103, 31);
        button1.setBackground(new Color(214, 217, 223));
        button1.setForeground(new Color(51, 153, 0));
        button1.setEnabled(true);
        button1.setFont(new Font("sansserif", 0, 12));
        button1.setText("Print Words");
        button1.setVisible(true);

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                insertwords(evt);
            }
        });


        button2 = new JButton();
        button2.setBounds(311, 341, 95, 31);
        button2.setBackground(new Color(214, 217, 223));
        button2.setForeground(new Color(51, 153, 0));
        button2.setEnabled(true);
        button2.setFont(new Font("sansserif", 0, 12));
        button2.setText("Answer");
        button2.setVisible(true);

        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                insertquestions(evt);
            }
        });


        panel1 = new JPanel(null);
        panel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(1));
        panel1.setBounds(22, 92, 179, 237);
        panel1.setBackground(new Color(214, 217, 223));
        panel1.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        panel1.setEnabled(true);
        panel1.setFont(new Font("sansserif", 0, 12));
        panel1.setVisible(true);

        panel2 = new JPanel(null);
        panel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(1));
        panel2.setBounds(229, 170, 258, 161);
        panel2.setBackground(new Color(214, 217, 223));
        panel2.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        panel2.setEnabled(true);
        panel2.setFont(new Font("sansserif", 0, 12));
        panel2.setVisible(true);

        textfield2 = new JTextField();
        textfield2.setBounds(74, 65, 89, 25);
        textfield2.setBackground(new Color(153, 153, 153));
        textfield2.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        textfield2.setEnabled(true);
        textfield2.setFont(new Font("sansserif", 0, 12));
        textfield2.setText("    Word List");
        textfield2.setVisible(true);

        textarea = new JTextArea();
        textarea.setBounds(10, 9, 156, 219);
        textarea.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        textarea.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        textarea.setEnabled(true);
        textarea.setFont(new Font("sansserif", 0, 12));
        textarea.setText("");
        textarea.setVisible(true);

        textarea2 = new JTextArea();
        textarea2.setBounds(9, 9, 237, 143);
        textarea2.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        textarea2.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        textarea2.setEnabled(true);
        textarea2.setFont(new Font("sansserif", 0, 12));
        textarea2.setText("");
        textarea2.setVisible(true);

        textfield5 = new JTextField();
        textfield5.setBounds(307, 140, 89, 28);
        textfield5.setBackground(new Color(153, 153, 153));
        textfield5.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        textfield5.setEnabled(true);
        textfield5.setFont(new Font("sansserif", 0, 12));
        textfield5.setText(" Answer Here:");
        textfield5.setVisible(true);

        textfield7 = new JTextField();
        textfield7.setBounds(164, 10, 175, 37);
        textfield7.setBackground(new Color(102, 102, 102));
        textfield7.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        textfield7.setEnabled(true);
        textfield7.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", 0, 18));
        textfield7.setText(" Unscrambler Game");
        textfield7.setVisible(true);

        contentPane.add(button1);
        contentPane.add(button2);
        contentPane.add(panel1);
        contentPane.add(panel2);
        contentPane.add(textfield2);
        panel1.add(textarea);
        panel2.add(textarea2);
        contentPane.add(textfield5);
        contentPane.add(textfield7);

        this.add(contentPane);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);


    }

    private void insertwords(ActionEvent evt) {

        Random r = new Random();

        String word1 = "application";
        String word2 = "programming";
        String word3 = "variable";
        String word4 = "method";
        String word5 = "class";
        String word6 = "package";
        String word7 = "import";
        String word8 = "boolean";
        String word9 = "debugger";
        String word10 = "syntax";
        String word11 = "compile";
        String word12 = "computer";

        String line1 = "-----------------------------------------";
        word1 = scramble(r, word1);
        String one = "#1- " + word1;
        word2 = scramble(r, word2);
        String two = "#2- " + word2;
        word3 = scramble(r, word3);
        String three = "#3- " + word3;
        word4 = scramble(r, word4);
        String four = "#4-  " + word4;
        word5 = scramble(r, word5);
        String five = "#5- " + word5;
        word6 = scramble(r, word6);
        String six = "#6- " + word6;
        word7 = scramble(r, word7);
        String seven = "#7- " + word7;
        word8 = scramble(r, word8);
        String eight = "#8- " + word8;
        word9 = scramble(r, word9);
        String nine = "#9- " + word9;
        word10 = scramble(r, word10);
        String ten = "#10- " + word10;
        word11 = scramble(r, word11);
        String elev = "#11- " + word11;
        word12 = scramble(r, word12);
        String twel = "#12- " + word12;
        String line2 = ("-----------------------------------------");

        textarea.setText(one + "\n" + two + "\n" + three + "\n" + four + "\n" + five + "\n" + six + "\n" + seven + "\n" + eight + "\n" + nine + "\n" + ten + "\n" + elev + "\n" + twel + "\n");


    }


    private void insertquestions(ActionEvent evt) {
        boolean incorrect = true;

        for (int attempts = 0; attempts < 3 && incorrect; attempts++) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("What is the answer to #1?");
            String answer1 = input.nextLine();

            if (!"application".equals(answer1)) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect. Hint: This runs on your computer.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Correct.");
                incorrect = false;

            }
        }
        boolean incorrect2 = true;

        for (int attempts = 0; attempts < 3 && incorrect2; attempts++) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("What is the answer to #2?");
            String answer2 = input.nextLine();
            if (!"programming".equals(answer2)) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect. Hint: Writing code for a computer.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Correct.");
                incorrect2 = false;
            }
        }
        boolean incorrect3 = true;

        for (int attempts = 0; attempts < 3 && incorrect3; attempts++) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("What is the answer to #3?");
            String answer3 = input.nextLine();
            if (!"variable".equals(answer3)) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect. Hint: A value in a program that can be changed.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Correct.");
                incorrect3 = false;
            }
        }

        boolean incorrect4 = true;

        for (int attempts = 0; attempts < 3 && incorrect4; attempts++) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("What is the answer to #4?");
            String answer4 = input.nextLine();
            if (!"method".equals(answer4)) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect. Hint: Tells the computer to do a procedure.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Correct.");
                incorrect4 = false;
            }
        }

        boolean incorrect5 = true;

        for (int attempts = 0; attempts < 3 && incorrect5; attempts++) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("What is the answer to #5?");
            String answer5 = input.nextLine();
            if (!"class".equals(answer5)) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect. Hint: Used to describe one or more objects in a program.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Correct.");
                incorrect5 = false;
            }
        }

        boolean incorrect6 = true;

        for (int attempts = 0; attempts < 3 && incorrect6; attempts++) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("What is the answer to #6?");
            String answer6 = input.nextLine();

            if (!"package".equals(answer6)) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect. Hint: Organizes a set of classes or interfaces.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Correct.");
                incorrect6 = false;
            }
        }

        boolean incorrect7 = true;

        for (int attempts = 0; attempts < 3 && incorrect7; attempts++) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("What is the answer to #7?");
            String answer7 = input.nextLine();
            if (!"import".equals(answer7)) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect. Hint: To send data from one program to another.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Correct.");
                incorrect7 = false;
            }
        }

        boolean incorrect8 = true;

        for (int attempts = 0; attempts < 3 && incorrect8; attempts++) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("What is the answer to #8?");
            String answer8 = input.nextLine();
            if (!"boolean".equals(answer8)) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect. Hint: True or False?");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Correct.");
                incorrect8 = false;
            }
        }

        boolean incorrect9 = true;

        for (int attempts = 0; attempts < 3 && incorrect9; attempts++) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("What is the answer to #9?");
            String answer9 = input.nextLine();
            if (!"debugger".equals(answer9)) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect. Hint: Used to exterminate bugs.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Correct.");
                incorrect9 = false;
            }
        }

        boolean incorrect10 = true;

        for (int attempts = 0; attempts < 3 && incorrect10; attempts++) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("What is the answer to #10?");
            String answer10 = input.nextLine();
            if (!"syntax".equals(answer10)) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect. Hint: Set of rules to follow while programming.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Correct.");
                incorrect10 = false;
            }
        }

        boolean incorrect11 = true;

        for (int attempts = 0; attempts < 3 && incorrect11; attempts++) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("What is the answer to #11?");
            String answer11 = input.nextLine();
            if (!"compile".equals(answer11)) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect. Hint: To translate code into a understandable language for a machine.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Correct.");
                incorrect11 = false;
            }
        }

        boolean incorrect12 = true;

        for (int attempts = 0; attempts < 3 && incorrect12; attempts++) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("What is the answer to #12?");
            String answer12 = input.nextLine();
            if (!"computer".equals(answer12)) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect. Hint: What you are using right now.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Correct.");
                incorrect12 = false;
            }


        }

    }

    public void generateMenu() {
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu tools = new JMenu("Tools");
        JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");

        JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem("Open   ");
        JMenuItem save = new JMenuItem("Save   ");
        JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit   ");
        JMenuItem preferences = new JMenuItem("Preferences   ");
        JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem("About   ");


        file.add(open);
        file.add(save);
        file.addSeparator();
        file.add(exit);
        tools.add(preferences);
        help.add(about);

        menuBar.add(file);
        menuBar.add(tools);
        menuBar.add(help);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("swing.defaultlaf", "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new GUI();
            }
        });
    }


    public static String scramble(Random random, String inputString) {

        char a[] = inputString.toCharArray();

        for (int n = 0; n < a.length - 1; n++) {
            int k = random.nextInt(a.length - 1);

            char temp = a[n];
            a[n] = a[k];
            a[k] = temp;
        }

        return new String(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: The best solution is not to do this but instead to simply append text yourself to the JTextArea. Why try to force a linear console program onto an event driven GUI and thus make things more difficult than they have to be? You also have other unrelated problems with this code including the newbie mistake of using null layouts and `setBounds(...)`.

Comment: Ah, you're also using a Scanner based on System.in. Stop. Really, just stop, pause and re-think this entire program as you're fighting against the event driven model of the Swing library and are just making things **much** more difficult than they should be.

Comment: Yes, I am a novice of Java, sorry for the mistakes. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Yes, re-do this entire program. If absolutely must do what you're trying to do, you will have to learn about using multiple threads, and I don't think that you need all this.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, you don't want to shoe-horn a console program into a GUI as you're proposing since while this is do-able, it would require jumping through threading hoops, and would be programming *against* the event-driven paradigm of the GUI library.

Instead I strongly suggest that you "refactor" this program, that is re-structure and re-write it from the ground up, with an eye towards creating a robust set of classes that can work well in an event-driven environment. I would deconstruct the problem into non-GUI model classes and GUI or "view" classes, the most important being the former, the model.

For example for the model, consider creating the following classes:

- ScrambledWord: a class that takes and holds a test String, that takes and stores a "hint" String, that can produce a randomly scrambled version of the test String, that has a `public boolean evaluate(String)` method that can test a String to see if it is correct, and that has appropriate constructor, setters and getters.
- Student: a class that holds the test score of the student using your GUI
- Test: a class that holds a collection (such as an ArrayList) of ScrambledWord objects, that holds a Student object, that can iterate through this collection returning the next ScrambledWord in the list, that can change the test score for student.

Then for the GUI, consider creating

- a QuestionPanel JPanel that has a JLabel that displays the currently tested scrambled word, a JTextField where the user can type in their guess, and a JButton for when the student wants to submit their guess. If the guess is wrong, an error JOptionPane can be displayed that also shows the hint. If the guess is right, then the next question is shown. Perhaps also give it another JButton to allow the user to skip the current question if they can't solve it.
- A main JPanel that holds the Question JPanel and that allows the user to start the test, finish the test, that shows the user's score.

Key here will be the ActionListeners for the button(s). The submit button's listener will test the text in the JTextField against the currently displayed ScrambledWord object by calling its `evaluate(...)` method passing the text field's text in. If evaluate returns true, then increment the student's score and show the next question within the QuestionPanel JPanel, perhaps with a `public void setScrambledWord(ScrambledWord sWord)`

These are just suggestions that you can follow if desired or not, but again my main recommendation is to not try to force your console application into the GUI. You won't be a happy programmer if you do this.